# Parsing with Nokogiri - can't iterate over rows

Tags: ruby, parsing, nokogiri

For some reason this code is not working:

```
url = "http://www.ontariocourts.ca/decisions_index/2015.htm"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url)) 

doc.css("table.judtbl tr").each do |i|   
  title = i.at_css(".title p").content
  citation = i.at_css(".citation p").content

p title
p citation

end
```

I have been going nuts trying to figure out why. Please help me someone!! Why can't this iterate over rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the inner CSS selectors have no match so `at_css(...)` returns nil which probably causes `.content` to fail ungracefully.  Try this instead:

```
doc.css("table.judtbl tr").each do |tr|   
  title = tr.at_css(".title p")
  citation = tr.at_css(".citation p")
  next unless title && citation # Skip the row if it has no title/citation.
  puts "OK: #{title.text} -- #{citation.text}"
end
```